# Get Order datetime including timezone in email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, order-email, timezone

I try to modify default New Order email template.

Currently, I get order datetime by `{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('short')}}`.
It results `6/18/2015 12:18 PM`.

I want to include timezone following datetime, expected result is `6/18/2015 12:18 PM GMT+7`.

I dive into Magento Core code to understand how it works, then I try

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('short')}} {{var order.getCreatedAtStoreDate().getTimezone()}}
```

but it doesn't work.

I know that if it works, `getTimezone()` may result `Asisa/Saigon` instead of `GMT+7` as expected.

So, how to get order datetime including timezone?

Comment: You need to get the store timezone as `GMT+7` Right?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR: no, assume that my store locale is GMT+7, then I need to get the text `GMT+7` appending to default datetime (only date and time)

Comment: ok i'll try the code and give the answer

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native function to get the GMT time value.

To get the GMT value of order created datatime.

I have `rewrite` the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and write new function to get the GMT.

(Refer magento model rewrite [**Tutorial**](http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/))

```
public function getGmtValue()
{
    $timeZone = $this->getCreatedAtStoreDate()->getTimezone();
    $currentTimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    date_default_timezone_set($timeZone);
    //Get GMT
    $value = date('P', strtotime($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate()));
    date_default_timezone_set($currentTimezone);
    return 'GMT'.$value;
}
```

Now you can get GMT value in email template by following code.

```
{{var order.getGmtValue()}}
```

I have refer these two links to get the GMT value

[1.how do i get greenwich mean time in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-greenwich-mean-time-in-php/9328760#9328760)

[2.datetime to timestamp in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225216/datetime-to-timestamp/6225264#6225264)

Comment: Thank you. I've tested your modification and it worked. 
Anyway I will leave the question unanswered for a short time to get more attentions for other solutions without modifying the Core codes or requiring extensions.